# Post запрос используя requests

Tags: python, requests

Есть такая форма для POST

```
type_list: Подавшие заявления
list_abitur: Бюджетная основа
faculty: Физический факультет
list_direction: 67
show_list: true
```

URL-encode:

```
type_list: %D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F
list_abitur: %D0%91%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0
faculty: %D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9+%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82
list_direction: 67
show_list: true
```

```css
import requests
import urllib

#Неработающие варианты
#Вариант 1
s = {"type_list":"Подавшие заявление","list_abitur":"Бюджетная основа", "faculty":"Физический факультет","list_direction":'67', "show_list":'true'}
req = requests.post('https://education.nsu.ru/abitura/',data=s)
print(req.text)
#Выводит null

#Вариант 2
req = requests.post('https://education.nsu.ru/abitura/',data={"type_list":urllib.parse.quote_plus("Подавшие заявление"),"list_abitur":urllib.parse.quote_plus("Бюджетная основа"), "faculty":urllib.parse.quote_plus("Физический факультет"),"list_direction":"67", "show_list":'true'})
print(req.text)
#Выводит null
```

Comment: Всё прекрасно работает. Код `200`, запрос проходит успешно. Сервер возвращает `null`. Это тоже ответ. Проверьте сами, напечатайте `req.status_code`.

Comment: Да, но я знаю, что он должен отправить кучу UTF-8 символов, но отправляет `null`

Comment: Когда я использовал `libcurl`, то так и происходило. Сервер отправлял данные про людей

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не очень здорово задавать `data` именно таким образом.
Лучше задать пост-данные не как `string`, а как `dict`.

И не вставлять сразу `URL encoded` текст, а кодировать его в коде.
И по-хорошему запрос тоже лучше отправлять через `urlib`, но т.к. я сам не особо им пользовался - покажу связку `requests + urlib.parse`

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlencode, quote_plus

headers = {
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
}

data = {'type_list': 'Подавшие заявления',
'list_abitur': 'Бюджетная основа',
'faculty': 'Физический факультет', 
'list_direction': '67', 
'show_list': 'true'
 }
data = urlencode(data, quote_via=quote_plus)
r = requests.post('https://education.nsu.ru/abitura/', data=data, headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```